# Has Apple added universal TRIM support with OS 10.8.4?

Tags: macos, ssd, trim

I used to enable TRIM using 3rd party software, and I had to do it all the time Apple released a minor upgrade. Recently I installed OS X 10.8.3 on a SSD and when I was ready to install the SSD in a new MBP, 10.8.4 came out. I installed the SSD in the laptop and upgraded to 10.8.4.  To my surprise TRIM was enabled.

Anybody else with the same experience? My SSD is a 512 GB Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that in my case installing OSX 10.8.4 on a new SSD I had to enable TRIM with TRIM Enabler.

When I first ran TRIM enabler the application displayed that TRIM was not enabled.

How did you determine that TRIM was enabled?